# Getting certificate chain from rejected connections in firefox

Tags: ssl, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions, browser-addons

I am able to get the chains well if I use [browser.webRequest.getSecurityInfo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/getSecurityInfo) inside a [browser.webRequest.onHeadersReceived](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onHeadersReceived) listener during a regular https connection, but if the connection failed due to a security issue such as an [expired certificate](https://expired.badssl.com/) then `onHeadersReceived` never gets triggered.
If I accept the bad certificate then `onHeadersReceived` does get triggered, but the security info does not contain the bad certificate.

I tried looking at [browser.webRequest.onErrorOccurred](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onErrorOccurred) and [browser.webRequest.onCompleted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onCompleted) but had no luck in getting `getSecurityInfo` to work in those contexts

I know the browser itself has this information because you can get it to display the certificate chain in the built in viewer (which can display arbitrary certificates in the format of `url_encode(base64_encode(DER_certificate)`)

Does any one know how can I get either nice certificate objects or at least the DER bytes (encoded or not, it doesn't matter) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I accept the bad certificate then onHeadersReceived does get triggered, but the security info does not contain the bad certificate.

This is a [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1678492) in Firefox.

> I tried looking at browser.webRequest.onErrorOccurred and browser.webRequest.onCompleted but had no luck in getting getSecurityInfo to work in those contexts

Like the documentation says: `getSecurityInfo` only works in `onHeadersReceived`. There are two related bugs, [1499592](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1499592) and [1474657](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1474657), to make getSecurityInfo work with other listeners as well.

Comment: ahh, that explains it. I see you are also trying to get this fixed, bless you for nudging this along!